# What is a typical class of issues that is caused by mutable data types in a single-threaded environment?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, immutability, mutable

JS models concurrency by an event loop. As a result there are no race conditions. So what are the drawbacks of the following type safe operation in the main scope of a program that would justify any caveat:

```
const m = new Map([["foo", true]]);

//...

m.set("bar", false);
```

Even if I'd empty `m` this shouldn't raise any issues, since every operation that depends on `m` should consider the empty case anyway.

Maybe someone can illustrate a typical class of issues that comes along with mutable data types.

I know that this question might be too opinion based so please feel free to close it if you think it doesn't fit SO.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A lot of them faded with TypeScript, as it enforces you to check every time as long as correct types are provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> JS models concurrency by an event loop. As a result there are no race conditions.

Let's stop right there. You might not get two different *threads* that try to access the same memory location at the same time, but you can still have concurrent parts of your program access mutable state asynchronously and ignore the fact that they are not alone. This is still a race condition.

A simple example:

```js
var clock = out.value = 0;

async function incrementSlowly() {
  if (clock == 12)
    clock = 0; // reset
  await delay(1000);
  clock++;
  out.value = clock;
}
function delay(t) { return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t)); }
```

```html
<output id="out"></output>
<button onclick="incrementSlowly()">Tick!</button>
```

The `clock` value will never get greater than 12? Try yourself what happens when you hit the button quickly.

The multiple invocations of the `incrementSlowly` function are running independently, and are doing the check at the wrong time - during their delay, another instance might already have incremented the `clock` again.

In this example, I've used a mutable variable, but it's the same for using mutable data structures. And it's not always as obvious when there are multiple agents accessing the structure through different methods.

Using immutable data structures forces you to make stateful operations explicit, and it would have become clear that `incrementSlowly` actually accesses the state twice.

Comment: I think your example rather reveals another flaw of the `Promise` type. [See the full response](https://gist.github.com/ivenmarquardt/21271e91000a56c3522ad62eeb00114b).

Comment: @bob Rename your file to `race-conditions.md`. Markdown supports code snippets. So, it should look exactly like your original answer.

Comment: @bob That has nothing to do with promises per se, the same would have happened if you used `setTimeout` directly. The `await` is just easier to miss than a nested callback, concealing the asynchrony better :-)

Comment: @AaditMShah _...isn'tt really a refutation of Bergi's answer_ - can you elaborate? I know I've already taken too much of your time..

Comment: @bob Posted an explanation on your gist.

Comment: Gist of @AaditMShah gist comment: My statement is wrong. If we have concurrency and mutability, we have race conditions. Asynchronous computations are the concurrency mechanism of the event loop. Hence there may be race conditions in connection with mutable data.

Answer (score 0):

> [...] since every operation that depends on `m` should consider the empty case anyway

Naming things is difficult. Assuming things *can* be dangerous.

I consider myself a pragmatic developer and sometimes mutation just has to happen. However it is your job to know what could go wrong and educate the people around you about the danger so that they can make informed decisions.

I once pointed out during a code review that this function was mutating its parameter: (it roughly looked like this)

```js
function foo(bar) {
  const baz = {...bar};
  baz.a.b.c = 10;
  return baz;
}
```

To which the author of the function replied "Nope, I've cloned it before. So the function is 'pure'".

Had I not spent the time to sit down with that person we could have had a major production issue. It turned out that they were mutating the application state and we had several false positive tests as a result.

This to me is the worse that can possibly happen when mutating data: confusion.

**Bugs caused by mutation can be difficult to trace back.**

I always encourage people in my team to not code for the "impossible case" because that often leads to code cluttered with "just in case" checks which increases the effort of maintainance and undermines our confidence in the code.

However the "impossible case" is just waiting around the corner if you allow *uncontrolled* access to your data.

I've already demonstrated that people do mutate things without realising it. When you've got people with different level of experience in your team the best you can do is:

1. Never assume anything
2. Teach them
3. Use a library to enforce immutability

Perhaps not the "academic" answer you were possibly expecting but I thought I could share some tips.

Comment: Confusion or losing the ability to reason about code in an equational manner was my first apprehension as well. However, I usually don't think about specific values while coding but about types. Consequently, as long as types don't change I feel kinda safe. Can you provide such an _impossible case_ for the mutable data type scenario?

Answer (score 0):

> JS models concurrency by an event loop. As a result there are no race conditions.

This is not entirely exhaustive, you can also obtain concurrency in javascript by running your program across multiple [child processes](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/node-js-child-processes-everything-you-need-to-know-e69498fe970a/), in which case having multiple threads able to mutate the same memory reference could indeed lead to race conditions or deadlocks. And yes, Immutability is one of the design patterns adopted to guarantee [thread-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety): *[by basically] enforcing shared data to be read-only*.

This is a good [article](https://netjs.blogspot.com/2015/06/race-condition-in-java-multi-threading.html) explaining why and how you could encounter race conditions in a multi-threading environment such as java.

---

You are right, there is nothing wrong about mutating memory references in single-threaded languages, actually this is how things have been done for a very long time in javascript. Immutability gained momentum only recently. [Hillel Wayne](https://hackernoon.com/mutability-leads-to-suffering-23671a0def6a) also explains how removing concurrency entirely helps to lift away the pain caused by mutability.

But I'd rather tackle this question from a different perspective: **Mutability represents an architectural problem** and it is transversal to every programming language or environment, whether it is multi or single-threaded doesn't really matter.

It's easy to realise, by thinking with architecture in mind, how mutability leads to unpredictable software. Does anything guarantee that given some conditions that object will be in a determinate state? Not really. How many entities can cause a change on the state of a given object? Can those changes be under control? Not really, think of a variable in the main scope... literally anything could impact on its state and assumptions like "*every operation should consider [...]*" are unsafe and very error prone.

So, while mutability is not necessarily wrong, **Immutability is another tool on your developer's toolkit** and mastering it makes you a better developer.

An Immutable Data Structure (unchangeable object) only supports one operation: read, and this makes your program behave like a Moore Machine: **given a specific moment in time, your program will always be in one of its possible states**.

Your program is a pipe of operations that can always be calculated and measured:

```js
R.pipe(
  R.toUpper, // You know the state of your program here
  R.concat(R.__, '!!'), // or here
)('Hello World'); // or here
```

you could also swap one of its stages with its returned value and still have your program behave as expected:

```js
R.pipe(
  R.always('HELLO WORLD'),
  R.concat(R.__, '!!'), 
)('Hello World');
```

Immutability also enables time travelling and makes testing very easy, but what's really important is that **it makes very easy to reason about states and their transitions** just because you treat every value as it was a primitive: `user.set('name', 'Giuseppe')` becomes no different than `'Giuseppe'.toUpperCase()`.

Your program is ultimately a well determined series of snapshots over time:

```js
-> 'Hello World' -> 'HELLO WORLD' -> 'HELLO WORLD!!'
t(0) ----------- t(1) ----------- t(2) ------------- t(n)
```

---

Notes: Whereas you have more intermediate values, Immutability also gives you a performance gain since it makes deep equality pointless.

```js
const user = { name: 'Giuseppe' };
const equals = (given, expected) => given === expected;

const newUser = { ...user, name: 'Marco' };

console.log('are users equals:', equals(user, newUser));
```

You would need a deepEqual function to obtain the same result with mutability... (read more on the [redux website](https://redux.js.org/faq/immutable-data#why-does-reduxs-use-of-shallow-equality-checking-require-immutability))

Comment: The thing is that comparing references breaks referential transperency, an effect that might be harmful as well. I think that a lot of equality checks scattered all over your code may indicate a wrong or at least dubious approach, as with React's "diffing" algo. Instead of working with diff trees they should conduct incremental updates. Thanks for your efforts anyway!